# Init UIViewController depending on the iPad orientation

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I'm try to initialize my UIViewController depending on the orientation of the iPad. 
In initWithNibName, I'm using the following code:

```
CGSize size = self.view.frame.size;
authForm = [[[AuthForm alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-400,(size.height-400)/2,400,400)] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:authForm];
```

This is what I want when the application starts up in portrait mode (upside-down or not), but I want to have this when it starts up in landscape mode (left or right):

```
authForm = [[[AuthForm alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((size.width-400)/2,-400,400,400)] autorelease];
```

How could I do that?
I already tried a few things with `willAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` but it didn't work.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825696/switch-between-multiple-views-while-respecting-orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I didn't apparently went far enough in the posts about this topic. 
I finally found this :

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
   authForm = [[[AuthForm alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((size.width-400)/2,-400,400,400)] autorelease];
} else {
   authForm = [[[AuthForm alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-400,(size.height-400)/2,400,400)] autorelease];
}
```

Thanks anyway